# Parse a string date into date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, swift3

```
let date = "2016-05-31T19:00:00+02:00"

let dateFormatterWithTime: DateFormatter {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z"
    return df
}
let thisIsNil = dateFormatterWithTime.date(from: date)
```

What is wrong with the formatter? According to http://nsdateformatter.com/ it returns a valid date, but I'm getting nil from this

Comment: Your pattern has a space before the UTC offset specifier. Your value doesn't have that space. That may not be all that's wrong, but it's what I'd start with.

Comment: can you explain briefly why would you add those since its already working?

Comment: There's no reason to set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `formatter` should be "`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`".
Mark that the Z, that is meant for Zone have no gap in between second and Zone in your date but in your format there is a Gap

Hence the code should be

```
    let date = "2016-05-31T19:00:00+02:00"

    var dateFormatterWithTime: DateFormatter {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        return df
    }
    let thisIsNil = dateFormatterWithTime.date(from: date)

    print("date \(thisIsNil)")
```

Output Log:

```
date Optional(2016-05-31 17:00:00 +0000)
```